# apDiv vs Table vs Div tag

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm new to web design. I hear that is not good to use table for creating webpage layout. But I try the option in Dreamweaver CONVERT/table to apDiv

My question is:

Is this a good metod for design a web page layout?
Is better to use div tag or apDiv?
What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good method for designing a web page layout?

No. There's only one good way. Start with the unmarked-up content. Mark it up by hand using the appropriate semantics of the elements and attributes of HTML. Bind layout instructions as CSS rules to those elements and attributes using CSS selectors.